# PHP decimal to egineering notation function

Tags: php

I have been looking up and down the PHP manual to find the answer to this, I even searched SO for it, I am looking for a function to convert any given decimal number to engineering notation to a fixed number of decimals.

for example

12345678 in engineering notation fixed to 2 decimals would be 12.35e6
489258239551 in engineering notation fixed to 5 decimals would be 489.25824e9

now I know about the sprintf function which gives me scientific notation and not engineering notation

```
echo sprintf("%.2e","12345678");
```

gives me 1.23e+7

```
echo sprintf("%.5e","489258239551");
```

gives me 4.89258e+11

nieither of those are in proper engineering format.

has anyone come across a function that does this?

Comment: What is proper engineering format for you? `sprintf` with argument `e` is generating scientific notation with given precision. There is no difference between `489.25824e9` and `4.89258e+11` other than precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need it to be reversible I recommend using `substr`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Write a function that gets a number loads it into a string variable and returns sub string (substr) based on conditions

You can get the string length using `strlen`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: can you rephrase your question in ext ?